# How to use instanceof with scala object?

Tags: java, scala, instanceof

I've the following scala hierarchy:

```
sealed trait SessionResult[+T] {
  def toOption: Option[T]
}

object SessionResult {
  trait SessionValue[T] extends SessionResult[T] {
    def session: T
    def toOption: Option[T] = Some(session)
  }
  trait NoSessionValue[T] extends SessionResult[T] {
    def toOption: Option[T] = None
  }

  case class Decoded[T](session: T) extends SessionResult[T] with SessionValue[T]
  case class CreatedFromToken[T](session: T) extends SessionResult[T] with SessionValue[T]

  case object NoSession extends SessionResult[Nothing] with NoSessionValue[Nothing]
  case object TokenNotFound extends SessionResult[Nothing] with NoSessionValue[Nothing]
  case object Expired extends SessionResult[Nothing] with NoSessionValue[Nothing]
  case class Corrupt(e: Exception) extends SessionResult[Nothing] with NoSessionValue[Nothing]
}
```

But I use this code from java and the following piece of code does not compile:

```
SessionResult<SomeSession> sr = ...
System.out.println(sr instanceof NoSession)
```

Why? And also how can I use `instanceof` to check the class of scala's object?

The error I'm getting is:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast SessionResult<SomeSession> to NoSession.
```

Comment: why exactly does it not compile? i would guess, because you already know that `sr instanceof SessionResult<SomeSession>`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I get: _Inconvertible types; cannot cast SessionResult<SomeSession> to NoSession_.

Comment: then look at what i said next in my previous comment. i am pretty sure that is the reason

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but I need to get the particular type.

Comment: try something like `sr.get(0) instanceof NoSession` or `sr instaceof SessionResult<NoSession>`

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. The error message seems to be fairly clear: you are checking if a variable of type `SessionResult<SomeSession>` is an instance of `NoSession`, which can never be the case, so compiler rejects it.

Comment: i guess the `NoSession` and `SomeSession` both extend the same super class while `SessionResult` does not. therefore you can only check if each element of `SessionResult` (as long as it is a list) is of type `NoSession`. for more help please tell us what exactly these classes are and what super classes they extend if they do

Comment: Using cast is generally not the better solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you're putting a hard bound on the generic parameter - `NoSession` is a `SessionResult[Nothing]`.

So (in Java parlance) the only compatible variant of `SessionResult<T>` compatible to `SessionResult.NoSession$` can be `SessionResult<Nothing$>`.

i.e. this will compile

```
public SessionResult<Nothing$> test() {

    return null;
}

public void blah() {
    if(test() instanceof SessionResult.NoSession$) {
    }
}
```

while e.g. this won't

```
public <T> SessionResult<T> test() {

    return null;
}

public void blah() {
    if(test() instanceof SessionResult.NoSession$) {
    }
}
```

Fortunately, since `NoSession` is an `object`, hence you can just reference-test the singleton value:

```
SessionResult.NoSession$.MODULE$.equals(test());
```

(`equals` is required as due to the variance you need upcast to `Object` - you can do that manually, but `equals` saves you some time on that)

---

Alternatively, you can just selectively wildcard the generic parameter, i.e.:

```
public static SessionResult<?> testYay() {
    return SessionResult.NoSession$.MODULE$;
}

public static SessionResult<?> testNay1() {
    return null;
}

public static SessionResult<?> testNay2() {
    return SessionResult.Expired$.MODULE$;
}

public static <T> SessionResult<T> testNay3() {
    return null;
}

public static void blah() {
    //prints true
    System.out.println(testYay() instanceof SessionResult.NoSession$);
    //prints false
    System.out.println(testNay1() instanceof SessionResult.NoSession$);
    //prints false
    System.out.println(testNay2() instanceof SessionResult.NoSession$);
    //prints false (and compiles)
    System.out.println((SessionResult<?>) testNay3() instanceof SessionResult.NoSession$);
}
```

This is a very hacky solution, but probably the most convenient for code that mostly deals with such equality checks in Java. As demonstrated in the `testNay3`, you can limit the "collateral damage" of using generic types this way via simple in-place casts.

**EDIT:** *changed to wildcard as per [Alexey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov?tab=topactivity) hint.*

Comment: I'd prefer `SessionResult<?>` to raw `SessionResult`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov : arghh, completely forgotten about Java wildcards! Thanks for the hint!